# How to detect the download Lollipop process from adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I want to understand the name of the process which download the Android Lollipop version.

From adb shell, I tried with "ps" command but I don't know the correct name of that process.

Can someone help me?

Comment: why you want to know ?

Comment: @maveňツ I want to kill it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way [image]

Select that specific process

Press on `stop` to kill that specific process(`pid`).

---

If you want to kill without ddms :

Use this to list the processes and their pid's

```
adb shell ps
```

---

and go for the kill using

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Where `<PID>` is the Process you want to kill (int)

---

### If you want to know the name of the process/package

- Open ActivityD in your application
- Press Home button
- Press Stop in DDMS on your application (this will kill the app process)

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that I didn't know the pid and the process name so from adb was very difficult to use kill command.

Comment: happy to help always ツ

Comment: Another way is to use monitor program in tools directory of adt. This solution avoid to use eclipse and give other features to manage the device.